# Human female chest model or data representation?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, computational-model

I am looking for professionally used representation of female chest (I know how it sounds ;). Generally - a model comprehensive enough to effectively represent human chest, with focus on breasts.

The data it needs to represent are at least: width, height, depth, distance between cardinal points, so on. I do know there's a questionnaire for patients willing to undergo an implant operation - I'm looking around for something similiar. Optimally the model would be directed towards computer represenation.

With that in mind, I've checked some computer implementations:

- SOFA (seems promising, but somewhat generic),
- MakeHuman (nice
  customization, but again, pretty general).

I do not know whether this question is in scope of this site. If it's too specific, then consider the simplified: what are the methods used to describe female chests OR what would be a good source of information about these methods?

Comment: What is the purpose for (ostensibly) a breast model? These are commonly used in radiotherapy models but I am not familiar enough to point you to a data source.

Comment: @leonardo, for exactly that - to export it to DICOM for radiotherapists.